# How to set-up a shelf in a tiled bathroom?

Tags: tile, screws

I am contemplating installing a shelf in my bathroom, and have set my sights on Ikea's Brogrund (number 304.089.79 in France, not sure is those are worldwide).

The screws to set it up on the wall are not included, and I have no idea of how to proceed.

[image: Exerpt from the instructions]

My bathroom walls are tiled:

[image: Photo of the bathroom]

The left-hand side wall is an outside wall, so its tile|drywall|insulating foam|concrete.
The right-hand side wall is an inside wall, so its tile|drywall

- Should I drill in a tile, or between them?
- What kind of screw do I need? It is the same kind for both walls?

Answer (score 2):

You have some nice tile there. It would be a shame to drill holes in it.

If you look at the customer reviews on the IKEA product page you can see this. You might want to consider that.

[image]

<sup>*[Review Source](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/brogrund-corner-wall-shelf-unit-stainless-steel-30408979/)*</sup>

If you do decide to use 3M Outdoor Mounting Tape some things to consider:

1. This tape is considered a permanent mounting system.
2. Make sure that both rails of the assembled shelf fit nice and flat against the walls on both sides of the corner where you intend to mount the unit.
3. You will want to make sure that the walls and rails are clean and free of any soap or oil film. I recommend a final cleaning with alcohol.
4. Attach the tape to the rails after you have fully assembled the shelf frame.
5. Attach the tape to the rails full length. If two runs fit the width of the rail then cover the full rail width.
6. Push the shelf unit into the corner carefully so that the two rails come into contact with the walls at the same time.

I have used this tape in the past and it adheres like crazy. Using it to mount metal rails really does mean that it will be there for the duration.

The tape seems to me to offer an advantage over the recommended two screws at just the top. It will hold the shelf securely in the corner without the bottom end being able to pull out from the corner.

Comment: Totally agree with Michael. Don't take a chance on chipping that nice tile job. Get the 3M  waterproof tape and tape those two vertical  members of the shelf to the tile.+